# How can I pass multiple dropdown values as URL parameters?

Tags: jquery, forms, codeigniter, validation, filtering

I've tried to create a live filter using url parameters with JQuery and I kinda made it but I have some more issues to solve.

Even though the selected value of each selected dropdown box is passed in the url, the values in the dropdowns return to zero values.

```
$('#filters select').change(function(){

  var string = $(this).attr('id');
  var value = $(this).val();

  $(this).each(function(){
    window.location.search += string + '=' + value + '&';
  })
});
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-2" id="filters">

        <div class="form-group mt-3">
          <select class="form-control filter-selection" id="petStatus">
            <option value="" selected>-- Status --</option>
            <option value="2">Found</option>
            <option value="1">Lost</option>
          </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group input-group">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-paw"></i></span>
          </div>
          <select class="form-control filter-selection" id="petType">
            <option value="" selected>-- Type --</option>
            <option value="1">Cat</option>
            <option value="2">Dog</option>
            <option value="3">Other</option>
          </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group input-group">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-venus-mars"></i></span>
          </div>
          <select class="form-control filter-selection" id="petGender">
            <option value="" selected>-- Gender --</option>
            <option value="1">Male</option>
            <option value="2">Female</option>
          </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group input-group">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-calendar"></i></span>
          </div>
          <select class="form-control filter-selection" id="petSize">
            <option value="" selected>-- Size --</option>
            <option value="1">Big</option>
            <option value="2">Mid-size</option>
            <option value="3">Small</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
```

I've searched all over the internet for solutions but noone had the same problem.

Any thoughts or suggestions?!

Thank you!

[EDIT] I found the solution on that, here's what i did:

```
$(function(){
  let query = new URL(location).searchParams;
  $("#petStatus").val(query.get("petStatus"));
  $("#petType").val(query.get("petType"));
  $("#petGender").val(query.get("petGender"));
  $('#filters select').change(function(){
      let filters = [];
      $('#filters select').each(function(){
          const string = $(this).attr('id');
          const value = $(this).val();
          if(value != '') {
            filters.push(string + '=' + value);
          }
      });
      window.location.search = filters.join('&');
  });

})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you change the location href or search, your site will usually reload. You can either manipulate location.hash without triggering a reload, or collect all the parameters you need, set location.search, and restore the form state by reading out the url parameters again or store things in the browser.

alternatively, you could look at the history api.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this. Don't forget to make your own `filterContent` function and don't forget to load the URL into the different `select`

```js
function filterContent() {
  document.querySelector('#filtered-content').innerHTML = 'Applied filters' + window.location.search;
}
$(document).ready(() => {
  // TODO load values from URL into select
  $('#filters select').change(function() {
    let filters = [];
    $('#filters select').each(function() {
      const string = $(this).attr('id');
      const value = $(this).val();
      if (value !== '') filters.push(string + '=' + value);
    })
    window.history.pushState({
      page: 'filtered'
    }, 'Filtered', '?' + filters.join('&'));
    filterContent();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-2" id="filters">

  <div class="form-group mt-3">
    <select class="form-control filter-selection" id="petStatus">
      <option value="" selected>-- Status --</option>
      <option value="2">Found</option>
      <option value="1">Lost</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group input-group">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-paw"></i></span>
    </div>
    <select class="form-control filter-selection" id="petType">
      <option value="" selected>-- Type --</option>
      <option value="1">Cat</option>
      <option value="2">Dog</option>
      <option value="3">Other</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group input-group">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-venus-mars"></i></span>
    </div>
    <select class="form-control filter-selection" id="petGender">
      <option value="" selected>-- Gender --</option>
      <option value="1">Male</option>
      <option value="2">Female</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group input-group">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-calendar"></i></span>
    </div>
    <select class="form-control filter-selection" id="petSize">
      <option value="" selected>-- Size --</option>
      <option value="1">Big</option>
      <option value="2">Mid-size</option>
      <option value="3">Small</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="filtered-content"></div>
```

Comment: This kinda works but if i select an option in another dropdown the value is not added with "&" or something. It's just been replaced. I want to add each selected value in the url. Any thoughts?!

Comment: As @VIJAY mentioned just check if you have a value... and see edit!

Comment: Nope, still the same! It just keeps replacing the strings.

What i mean is that if i select the first dropdown, the value is added properly e.g.  "?petStatus=1".

if i click the second dropdown though, the above value will be replaced with the id and value of the other dropdown, and it will not be added. let me add you the html code too, in case i made a mistake there.

Comment: This drives me crazy, when i click another option it the "selected" attribute is not changing and remains in the first option....

Comment: I hope you set the select fields according to the value that is passed in the url. If not, this will not work.

Comment: check the edit on top! I also posted the html code of the dropdowns!

Comment: I have already used your html. As I said in my previous comment,  if you do not pass the values from the url to the select fields, it will not work. I'll adopt the example to use pushstate, which will not reload the browser. But you'll have to call your filter function after that...

Answer (score 0):

Try with the sample code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="script.js"></script>
      <script>
         $(document).ready(function(){ 
         $('select').change(function(e){ 
           var parameters = "";
           $('select').each(function(){
             parameters += ($(this).attr('id')+"="+this.value+"&"); 
           });
           window.location.search +=parameters;
         });
         });
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
      <select id="Select1">
         <option value="1">Sri</option>
         <option value="2">Kumar</option>
         <option value="3">Dhana</option>
         <option value="4">Kishore</option>
      </select>
      <select id="Select2">
         <option value="1">Demo</option>
         <option value="2">Values</option>
         <option value="3">Soft</option>
      </select>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This adds every value even if it's not selected. I want to add it in the url only if a value is selected.

Any thoughts?!

Comment: You can just have a check like if(this.value!="") {  parameters += ($(this).attr('id')+"="+this.value+"&");  }

Comment: It keeps adding the values even if i change the already selected ones.

sth like: select1=1&select2=3&select1=2